# Sikuli Integrator C# - How to change the dircetory of SikuliOutputLog.txt?

Tags: automated-testing, c#, uiautomation, sikuli

I'm new with Sikuli Integrator in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio. May I kindly know how to change the directory of the `SikuliOutputLog.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't no much about Sikuli, but from the programming perspective i can give you an answer.

At the `AssemblyCleanup` level write a method to move/copy the existing `SikuliOutputLog.txt` to your custom location.

```
string source = "C:\\A\\SikuliOutputLog.txt";
File.Move(Source, "C:\\AA\\SikuliOutputLog.txt");
```